# Spoiler menu - A lot of content isn't actually hidden (on phone)

Tags: css

I have this simple spoiler menu using only CSS (and JS for the changing button text, but that's not important)

```
.spoilerbutton {
    display:block;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
.spoiler {
  background-color: lightGreen;
    overflow:hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.spoiler > div {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightGreen;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease;
}
.spoilerbutton[value="Show"] + .spoiler > div {
  background-color: lightGreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top:-100%;
}
.spoilerbutton[value="Hide"] + .spoiler > div {
  background-color: lightGreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:1px;
}
```

I added `box-sizing: border-box;` which made the issue not appear on PC. Now it only appears on phone devices:

[image]

(Spoiler button hasn't been clicked and some of the information is outside)

How I use it: (Javascript)

```
`<input class="spoilerbutton" type="button" value="Show" onclick="this.value=this.value=='Show'?'Hide':'Show';">
<div class="spoiler"><div>
  ${smetki}
</div></div>`
```

Comment: where is your html codes?

Comment: I add the spoilers via JS code. Updated OP.

Comment: make sure you have proper closing html tags, close you divs